# command line arguments are not retrieved

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

Note: I've already tried every solution on stackoverflow!

I'm using windows 10 and python 3.5. I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "geiger_plot.py", line 236, in <module>
    main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argv'
```

when I try to execute the script using every imaginable commands:

```
geiger_plot.py test
python geiger_plot.py test
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" geiger_plot.py test
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" C:\Users\Chaosuser\Desktop\GeigerLog\geiger_plot.py test test test
```

I already fixed the registry entries for python command line argument:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\pythonw.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\pythonw.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

(This is from an exported .reg - that's why there are thousands of backslashes.)
In the script itself I made everything right as far as I know. It's a script I want to execute from another script using an argument to pass it a file path (`logfile`). That always gave me errors, so I tried to run it from a shell directly.

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    sys.argv
    print(sys.argv)
    logfile = str(sys.argv[1])
```

It just doesn't even get there to give me errors about my use of `sys.argv`!

What is wrong?

SOLUTION was to remove argv:

```
def main(argv):
    print(sys.argv)
to
def main():
    print(sys.argv)
```

Man... python is made so easy its hard again!

Comment: Python doesn't execute a function called `main()` automatically. At the end of your script call it yourself with a `main(sys.argv)` statement. You might want to make that conditional with a `if __name__ == '__main__':` if your script could also be imported by another (where you probably wouldn't want `main()` to be run).

Comment: Don't write to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. That key is a merged view meant for *reading*. The result of writing to it is indeterminate. Be specific to the exact hive you want to update: `[HKLM | HKCU]\SOFTWARE\Classes`. Also, if your current user is actually configured to use the `Applications\python.exe` subkey, you've modified (broken) your Python installation. It should be using `Python.File` and `Python.NoConFile`, which should be using the py[w].exe launcher. The user choice is here (read-only): `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice`.

Comment: eryksun I did this manually and used the export function of regedit to get the keys for me to share with others. How is this: [HKLM | HKCU] specific? I looked into python.file and python.noconfile and they were alright from the start. Theres no py.exe nor pyw.exe, its python.exe in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `argv` parameter from main's signature and just use `sys.argv[1]` :

```
def main():
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

You also need to call main :

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: What is "mains signature"? def main(argv):? At the end of the script, put sys.argv or not? Whats the difference?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by mains signature. I just edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: There already was `if __name__ == '__main__':`  on the bottom. But i should probably just remove the argv from the signature. Ill try.... YES THAT was the solution. fgs, so simple...